# search with regex and increment int

Tags: regex, bash, sed, increment

I haver few files (same file name) with this text

```
version: 24
runtime: python27
```

How can I increment the version number in all of them from the cmd?

I can do easy `sed` command, but I'm looking for smart increment and not just replacing text

`sed -i '' -e 's/24/25/g' PATH`

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk '/^version:/ {$2++}; {print}' file
```

Or shorter:

```
awk '/^version:/ {$2++}1' file
```

Ouput:

```
version: 25
runtime: python27
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is not suitable for arithmetic operations, you can use `perl` here

```
$ perl -pe 's/\d+/$&+1/e if /version/' ip.txt 
version: 25
runtime: python27
```

- `s/\d+/$&+1/e` the `e` modifier allows Perl code in replacement section. `$&` contains the matched string (similar to `&` in sed), `$&+1` is the result you need

  - `if /version/` this substitution will happen only when input line contains `version`

For in-place editing, use `perl -i -pe 's/\d+/$&+1/e if /version/' /path/to/files`

See 
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for explanations on `-i` and `-pe` options

Answer (score 1):

sed surely does the job but it's not a good idea to stick to it. A little bash trick would be better.

```
VER=$(grep 'version' filename | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
sed -i "/version/s/$VER/$((VER+1))/" filename
```

It's really a trick because sed can't do arithmetic calculations, so I overloaded that job to bash and use sed to do text replacement only.

For convenience use, you may want to wrap them up:

```
incr_ver() {
  VER=$(grep 'version' "$1" | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
  (( $? )) || sed -i "/version/s/$VER/$((VER+1))/" "$1"
}
```

And apply them to each file:

```
for file in *
do
  incr_ver "$file"
done
```

Comment: Sorry this solution will work with single file and will not work with multiple file in single directory. To make it work with multiple file in directory you manually need to iterate the file of directory one by one. and apply this two mentioned command for each file one by one.

Comment: @AxT_8041 What about wrapping it up in a function?

Comment: That's what I wrote in comment. Still appreciate your thinking to use only `sed` for answer

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/version: /{h;s/.*\( [0-9]*\)/echo $((\1+1))/e;x;s/ .*//;G;s/\n/ /}' infile
```

Comment: I am shorted your solution: `sed -r 's/(version: )([0-9]*)/echo \1 $((\2+1))/e' input.txt`.